# MySQL create table script TEXT data_type syntax

Tags: mysql

Curfuffled on this sytax.  Tried looking, can't find on it anywhere.

```
CREATE TABLE `#__LISTINGS` (
  `Description` TEXT(M) NOT NULL
```

What is the value of M if I want to allow the max length?  I've read through the reference on mySQL's site, but it doesn't give an example or say what the default value is.

Comment: Is your table really named `#__LISTINGS`?

Comment: Shame. Great table name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't include `(M)` at all if you want the size to be unbound.

Comment: That's what I figured.  If I was brave enough, I would have just ran the script and see what happened.